# Primefaces 6 bar encode

Tags: charts, primefaces, jsf-2.2

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:95)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You have provided no code, no PrimeFaces version, basically no information at all. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: or http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ or http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ or http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the extender attribute Ext is not defined in primefaces -6 and also mention the type of chart as bar

Comment: Great you solved it... But id you'd have posted a good [mcve], we could have seen that very quickly...